# Is there a strict proof of the statement that a reversible process is always quasi-static?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, reversibility

**I'm wondering if there is a clear proof of "a reversible process is always quasi-static".** I really don't know whether this generally accepted idea is based on the strict mathematical proof or an intuition from experiences.

Could you give me some comments about this?

It looked [Reversible and Quasi-static processes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160495/reversible-and-quasi-static-processes) gives the answers but I think this answer is still statements rather than the proof.